# Auto import Intellij IDEA java style formatter file when project is opened

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to setup my project when it is opened in Intellij IDEA, the code format xml file should be auto set. I have created the file using Code Styles -> java -> Export to File feature. Now I have xml file which defined the custom java style and  I intend to add this file as project source. When other team members open the project I need Intellij IDEA to load the java style from this given file automatically. Is this possible ? If so how ? I could not found a way to this from a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open settings:   Preferences | Editor | [Code Style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.2/settings-code-style.html)

There is small icon near to Scheme, after click you can:

> You can copy the IDE scheme (Default) to the current project, using the Copy to
>   Project... command.

and you see now in: [`.idea/codeStyles/`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copying-code-style-settings.html): `codeStyleConfig.xml` and `Project.xml`

You can share settings with whole team by committing these files into version control repository (git for example).
You can also [share](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html#common) run configurations - see [How do I share IntelliJ Run/Debug configurations between projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642147/how-do-i-share-intellij-run-debug-configurations-between-projects)
 (`.idea\runConfigurations`)

See also:

- Sharing Your IDE Settings - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46144716
- https://tips.seebrock3r.me/share-the-settings-with-the-whole-team-android-studio-protip-6-3cce16eb2ea4
- https://tips.seebrock3r.me/share-settings-with-the-team-a-year-later-e28c24fc07aa